# expected primary-expression before ‘struct’

Tags: c++, struct

Both GCC 8.3.0 and clang 9.0.1 fail to compile this short example code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
struct mystruct {
  T data;
};

int main (const int argc, const char * const * const argv) {
  int ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  auto elem1 = struct mystruct<bool> { }; // Doesn't compile.
  auto elem2 = mystruct<bool> { }; // Does compile.

  return (ret);
}
```

Error messages that come up:

```
teststruct.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char* const*)’:
teststruct.cpp:11:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘struct’
   auto elem1 = struct mystruct<bool> { }; // Doesn't compile.
                ^~~~~~
```

```
teststruct.cpp:11:16: error: expected expression
  auto elem1 = struct mystruct<bool> { }; // Doesn't compile.
               ^
```

I don't understand why the first expression seems to be some kind of illegal syntax.

As far as I know, the `struct` keyword can essentially be omitted in C++ **unless** there is ambiguity. This tends to happen (e.g., for `[struct] stat`, which can either be a structure or a function), so the `struct` keyword can and should be used to disambiguate in such scenarios.

In my example, however, using the `struct` keyword is downright harmful and I would have never expected that.

Since two different compilers are rejecting the code in exactly the same way, my best guess is that I'm missing some information, rather than this being a bug.

Comment: Just a guess, but I believe that you're just calling the constructor of mystruct, so putting struct keyword there makes no sense to the compiler. I get the same error with this code: struct test
{
    int data;
}

int main()
{
    auto temp = struct test;
}

Comment: You can add parentheses as `auto elem1 = (struct mystruct<bool>) { };`.

Comment: Yeah, but no. I'm creating a new object of type `[struct] mystruct` initialized to the values provided in the initializer list (which happens to be empty, so zero-initialized), which is then copied to the original variable. The copy is redundant, of course, but that's not the point. However, your points are interested in so far that the compiler might not see `struct mystruct<T>` as a type but rather as something else, which can be solved by wrapping the type in parens. Still... that sounds odd.

Comment: This is the same for creation of a temporary of any multi-word type. [`f(long long{1})` fails similarly](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca316e71a99bad3b).

Comment: @songyuanyao: That’s a compound literal, which is not C++ (but is often supported for C99 compatibility).

Comment: As much as I love `const`, that’s not a standard signature for `main`, even though `char**` *does* convert to `const char *const*` (not `const char**`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `type{…}` syntax, like `type(…)`, requires a **single**, non-elaborated type specifier.  This can be fairly complicated:

```
auto x=typename A::template B<int>();  // OK
```

It cannot, however, include operators or prefix specifiers:

```
// All bad:
auto a=int*{};
auto b=const int();
auto c=struct X{};  // a class definition?
auto d=struct Y {}();  // still not allowed
auto e=signed char();

auto f=signed();  // OK, means int
```

Such cases can of course be handled by `decltype` or by introducing *typedef-name*s:

```
void f(void());
void f(int*);
struct x {};
void g(x);
void g(unsigned long);
void h() {
  // Ambiguous:
  // f(nullptr);
  // Illustrative of the parsing difficulty:
  // f(void(*)()());
  f(decltype(&h)());
  int x;  // oh noes
  using y=struct x;
  g(y());
  g(decltype(1ul)());  // same as g(0);
}
```

Comment: Defined in the [\[dcl.typedef\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef), and template-name in simple-template-id in typedef-name should be a single identifier.

Comment: @yao99: That sounds right, but I’m not sure what conclusion you’re trying to draw from it.

Comment: Just paste the link to the doc. `:)`